# Understanding prototype and Object

Tags: javascript

I am sure their a several reference and great answers explaining prototype in Javascript,

My question happens to be simple, When I create something like this.

```
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
Person.prototype.nationality = "English";

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
var myMother = new Person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");
```

And console.log myFather it displays its firstName, LastName, age, eyeColor but no the nationality but when I do something like this..

`myFather.nationality` it displays nationality to be "english"

Now, I am running everything in chrome console log and my question is why does nationality does not appear by default in `console.log`  of `myFather` object

Comment: Because it's inherited. It also doesn't display `myFather.constructor`, `myFather.hasOwnProperty` or `myFather.isPrototypeOf`, despite all of them (and more) existing: they are usually not of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept here is **own property** vs **inherited property**

When you type `myFather.nationality`, the JSVM first checks if the `myFather` object itself has a property called `nationality`. If it does, then it will return that. In this case, we say that `nationality` is the object's **own property**. By default, objects do not have own properties; they get them when you directly assign them on the object, e.g. what you do in the constructor.

If not, it checks the prototype of the object; and then the prototype of the prototype; and so on, until it reaches the basic `Object` prototype, at which point it stops. If one of the prototypes in this chain has a property called `nationality`, then you will get that value. In this case, `nationality` is an **inherited property** of the object.

When you debug an object to the console, it only prints the own properties of the object.

By default, all objects have the basic `Object.prototype` as their prototype. If you define a constructor function, such as `Person`, then all objects you construct with that function (by calling `new Person()`) will instead have `Person.prototype` as their prototype.

You can get started on some deeper reading here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 1):

Because `nationality` is not an "OwnProperty" of `Person`, rather, is an implicit property of its prototype for every instatiated `Person` object.

If you need to check the properties of a specific Object, use the function `getPrototypeOf`.

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eye;
}

Person.prototype.nationality = "English";

var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(myFather))
```

Comment: Can you suggest some document to help me dive deeper into proto property. For some reason, I find Firefox documentation on this to be too confusing

Comment: @RahulPatel did you read: [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) or [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)??

Comment: @RahulPatel [JavaScript: Diagram to explain inheritance, __proto__ and prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155986/javascript-diagram-to-explain-inheritance-proto-and-prototype); [oop - How to inherit from a class in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107556/how-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-javascript)

Comment: @Andreas interesting resources!

Answer (score 0):

`nationality` is not *directly* on the Person object - it's one step above on the prototype chain, on the prototype. When you `console.log` it, click on `__proto__` and you will see `nationality: "English"`.

Comment: Can you suggest some document to help me dive deeper into _proto_ property. 
For some reason, I find Firefox documentation on this to be too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
console.log(myFather.__proto__);
```

Javascript searches for the key in the object, if not found it searches it in the **proto** of the object. If still not found , in the **proto** of the **proto** object. If you are new to this, I think you will find this blog very useful.

http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/how-prototypal-inheritance-really-works.html

P.S I know you don't want links to any blogs or reference, but trust me, this one will really clear your concepts